# How do I check whether a steam download has finished?

Tags: java, steam

I am a beginner and want to write a small Java project which notifies me when a stream download has finished. But I don't know how to check for it and can't find anything online.

It's weird to me, that i don't find anything when googling since stream is such a popular feature and the application is very simple.

Comment: If steam pre-allocates the file space needed, you could compare the "bytes on disk" vs. the "File size" attributes on a windows machine. As it downloads, it would slowly increase to being slightly over 100% of the file size (as size on disk will rarely match 100% the file size, since block size considerations come into play). "The application is very simple" is an assumption: some things that seem simple to a human are not so simple for a machine. Particularly without integration support from the program you're adding onto.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rogue but even then, he'd have to figure out where to look. The entire idea doesn't really work, because the Steam client -- to my knowledge -- has no API to attach helper programs...

Comment: @ChristianStieber it'd be a matter of tracking down the configuration that Steam uses and using it yourself. Not an insurmountable task, but reverse engineering can definitely become a time sink.

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't expect it to be this complicated. Still have a lot to learn